# Creating a new function in a seperate file and using a header file

Tags: c

My next step is to break my program into several functions outside the main code, in spate files and using a header file.

The first function I moved was the change to uppercase function and this works great.

I have now tried to create a new function to do the conversion to from Morse code to alphanumerical.  Seem to be getting plenty of errors.

I have attached my main program followed by the function programs followed by the header file.

MAIN PROGRAM

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#include "morse.h"

int main(void)
{

char *morse[] = {"/",".-","-...","-.-.","-..",".","..-.","--        .","....","..",".---","-.-",".-..","--","-.","---",".--.","--.-",".-        .","...","-","..-","...-",".--","-..-","-.--","--..","-----",".----        ","..---","...--","....-",".....","-....","--...","---..","----."};
char *alpha[] =  {" ", "A", "B",    
    "C",   "D",  "E","F",   "G",  "H",   "I", "J",   "K",  "L",   "M", "N",         "O",  "P",   "Q",   "R",  "S",  "T","U",  "V",   "W",  "X",   "Y",   "Z"        ,   "0",    "1",    "2",    "3",    "4",    "5",    "6",    "7",    "8",         "9"};


  char *print_array[50];
  int print_array_index = 0;

  char hold[50];
  int hold_index = 0;

  char input[200];
  int i = 0;

//Requesting input from the user
printf("Welcome to the Morse translator.\n");
    printf("Enter input: ");
    fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);

// Call to a function that converts user input to UPPERCASE
turnUpCase(input);

    if (input[0]=='-' || input[0]=='.')
    {
    //Calls the function to convert Morse code to Alpha
    morseToAlpha(input, *alpha, *morse);
}
    // this section is now in a seperate function
/*      while (input[i] !='\0') {

        if (input[i] ==' ' || input[i] == '\n')
        {
            hold[hold_index] = '\0';

            bool found = false;

            for (int x = 0; x < sizeof(morse) / sizeof(char *); x++)
            {
                if (strcmp(morse[x], hold) == 0)
                {
                    print_array[print_array_index++] = alpha[x];

                    found = true;

                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!found)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Invalid Morse code!");
                return 0;
            }

            hold_index = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            hold[hold_index++] = input[i];
        }

        i++;
    }
    for (int x = 0; print_array_index > x; x++)
    //for (int x = 0; x < print_array_index; x++)
    {
        printf("%s", print_array[x]);

    }

    printf("\n");
}

*/

else if (isalnum(input[0]))
{
    while (input[i]!='\0' && input[i] !='\n')
    {
        bool found = false;

        for (int x=0; x < sizeof(alpha)/sizeof(char*);x++)
        {
            if (*alpha[x]==input[i])
            {
                print_array[print_array_index++] =
   morse [x];


                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input!\n");
            return 0;
        }
        i++;

    }
    printf("%s",print_array[0]);
    for (int x=1; x < print_array_index; x++)
    {
        printf(" %s",print_array[x]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}           
    return 0;
}
```

My function that does is causing errors

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<string.h>
#include"morse.h"


void morseToAlpha(char *in, char *letters, char *code)
{
int i=0;
int x=0;

char *print_array[50];
int print_array_index =0;

char hold[50];
int hold_index = 0;



while (in[i] !='\0') 
{

        if (in[i] ==' ' || in[i] == '\n')
        {
            hold[hold_index] = '\0';

            bool found = false;

            for (int x = 0; x < sizeof(code) / sizeof(char *); x++)
            {
                if (strcmp(*code[x], hold) == 0)
                {
                    print_array[print_array_index++] = letters[x];

                    found = true;

                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!found)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Invalid Morse code!");
                return 0;
            }

            hold_index = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            hold[hold_index++] = in[i];
        }

        i++;
    }
    for (int x = 0; print_array_index > x; x++)
    //for (int x = 0; x < print_array_index; x++)
    {
        printf("%s", print_array[x]);

    }

    printf("+++++\n");
}
```

Current compile errors

morseToAlpha.c: In function 'morseToAlpha':
morseToAlpha.c:32:29: error: invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')

if (strcmp(*code[x], hold) == 0)
^
morseToAlpha.c:34:55: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
print_array[print_array_index++] = letters[x];
^
morseToAlpha.c:45:13: warning: 'return' with a value, in function returning void
return 0;
^

Comment: Add the errors you're getting.

Comment: You defined `morseToAlpha()` to take `char*`s as 2nd and 3rd parameter, but you pass `char**`. This mistake is completely independent to to how many files you distribute the source code.

Comment: Suggest two arrays is bad data structure (very hard to check), array of sctruct { char letter; char * morse; } will be better

Answer (score 1):

What you're creating here:

```
char *morse[]....;
char *alpha[]....;
```

is not a pointer to array. It is read as,

```
(char *)(morse[])..;
(char *)(alpha[])..;
```

`*morse` is then a pointer to a `char`.

In the function `strcmp(*code[x], hold)`,

`code` is a pointer to a `char`.

`code[x]` is a `char`.

But you're doing `*code[x]`.

An example which produces same error is,

```
int main() {
    char c = 'h';
    printf("%c\n", *c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about what your problem is, but this is what i think.

Split your work with separate file and put the different [function prototype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prototype) needed in header file.

If the project is small, you can put everything in the same directory, if the project is bigger, it would be nice to split in multiple directories and use a Makefile to compile your project.

```
srcs/file1.c
srcs/fileX.c
incs/header.h
Makefile
```

The question title is : *Creating a new function in a seperate file and using a header file*

So in that case. We will put your main fonction in a `main.c` file and the morseToAlpha in `morse.c` And the morse to alpha prototype in the header file `morse.h`

And compile your project with :

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror main.c morse.c morse.h
```

But you should take a look on [how to build a Makefile](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/makefile/)

Answer (score 0):

The code:

```
char *morse[] = {"/", ...};
char *alpha[] = {" ", ...};
```

first declares `morse` and `alpha` to be arrays of pointers to char, and then initializes these arrays. Now, a string literal like `"/"` is really an array of chars: `"/" = {'/', '\0'}`. So, the array `morse`, which is to be filled with pointers to char, is initialized to contain a pointer to char (namely, a pointer to the character literal `'/'`) as its first element.

When you want to process an array with a function, you call the function with the name of the array, and a pointer to the first element of the array is passed to the function. So your function call should look like:

```
morseToAlpha(input, alpha, morse);
```

This passes a pointer to input[0], which is a pointer to char, a pointer to alpha[0], which is a pointer to a pointer to char (i.e., a pointer to a string), and a pointer to morse[0], which is also a pointer to a pointer to char. Thus, your function should be declared as:

```
void morseToAlpha(char *in, char **letters, char **code);
```

I hope this helps :)